# iOS : My sound file can't play in PickerViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview, uipickerviewcontroller

I have one music player with multiple sound app using a pickerView controller but when i try to build the app, the sound doesn't come out. Anyone can help me to troubleshoot my code? Here is my code for troubleshooting.

.H file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

    UIPickerView       *picker;
    UILabel            *musicTitle;
    NSMutableArray     *musicList;
    AVAudioPlayer      *audioPlayer;


}


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *musicTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *musicList;

-(IBAction)playSelectedMusic:(id)sender;


@end
```

.M file

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            musicList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"music1",@"music2",@"music3",@"music4",@"music5",
                        @"music6",nil];
        }

    -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
          inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {



        if ([[musicList objectAtIndex:row] isEqual:@"music1"])
        {


            NSURL *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"music1" withExtension:@"mp3"];
            AVAudioPlayer *theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path error:NULL];


            theAudio.delegate = self;
            [theAudio play];

            NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                      @"music1",
                                      [musicList objectAtIndex:row]];
            musicTitle.text = resultString;


        }

-(IBAction)playSelectedMusic:(id)sender{

    how do i call the didSelectRow & put it here ?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

> try setting pickerview.delegate = self;
>
> will get invoked automatically once you set its delegate for the pickerview u dont need the >playSelected music button explicitly i hope.

Comment: i try to set pickerview.delegate = self; and i receive this error when build. Cannot find function pointer CreateAudio

Comment: i try to set pickerview.delegate = self; and i receive this error when build. In my console it says : Cannot find function pointer CreateAudio for factory in CFBundle/CFPlugIn  </Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/usb-audio.com.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)

Comment: pls kindly see this link https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2220669?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Hi, problem solved now. But, i need the action press button. How do i do so? -(IBAction)playSelectedMusic:(id)sender{

    how do i call the didSelectRow & put it here ?

}